# Mount door lever lock to iron fence gate?

Tags: mounting, fence, lock, gates

Does anyone know what the hardware would be called that I'd need to purchase in order to get a [door latch like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08B1G64KS) to mount to a standard [iron fence gate](https://www.lowes.com/pd/a/999990272) (i.e. vertical bar gate)?

The reason I'm not going with a surface mount option made for this purpose is because the only one I could find was the Sumo one which is $500 and it's a lot more than I was hoping to spend.

EDIT: note that this is primarily for child safety as opposed to adult security.

[image]

[image]

(Images are from the Amazon links)

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. That latch is for a _door_, which would have bores for the bolt and latch shaft. You need a [gate latch](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ALiCzsbtx5NLKsRwaQjptb0u8hzk6jDXtQ:1654115024237&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=combination+gate+latch). You _could_ make this work, but it would be a hassle.

Comment: @isherwood Yeah I totally agree, but the only one I could find which was made for this purpose is the $500 Sumo one which is surface mount and that's more than I'm hoping to spend.

Comment: Fair enough, but then your question is too broad. The hardware needed isn't _called_ anything. It's a matter of custom engineering with various parts and fasteners.

Comment: Couple of summary points in favor of the Sumo. Get the double sided model and you don’t need a massive plate to prevent people opening from the outside (or putting a loop of string over). They are quite well made and will put up with weather. OTOH, the instructions are a wall of text and are a trudge to get through. (And for context, I have a history degree, so should be able to understand written instructions.) Pretty sure my welder’s bill would be over $400 by the time he was done making the linked lock work.

Comment: Presuming that the 2nd picture is of the gate (or very similar to the gate) that is installed, what's to prevent me from reaching through and opening it by the inside handle? Unless my coffee was decaf this morning, this seems about as useful as a screen door on a submarine.

Comment: @FreeMan I'll be putting mesh or something to prevent reach through

Comment: ↑ pair of snips, you're in.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah though this is primarily for child safety as opposed to adult security.  The most secure possible gate still has the weak link of simply jumping the fence anyways.

Comment: For child safety, I'd simply mount the latch (or a second latch) up high out of reach of the child(ren). By the time they're old enough to reach the top of the gate, they _should_ be old enough to know better. It's not to keep other people out so the kids don't get snatched (a highly unlikely scenario in most parts of the world), so it's simply to keep them in. Also, keep climbing material out of the backyard, as small children quickly become monkeys when things are out of reach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardware is called a "gate box." They're offered as a pre-made component intended to be welded into a custom-built gate, although nothing about that says one couldn't begin with an off-the-shelf gate like the one pictured and customize it further.

[image: gate boxes]

A person who can weld the box into a gate could, with a little more time, fashion a custom box from sheet metal or other material they may have at hand.

As others have pointed out, one should consider what sort of threat the gate lock is intended to protect against. If it's simply to keep very young children out then the anti-defeat measures are much simpler than those needed to discourage a resourceful adult from defeating the lock.